# Terraform init reports Failed to query provider packages via Github Actions

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-gcp

Dunno what is going on and need your help. It works doing locally but via pipeline I keep getting issue on retrieving provider packages.

My github configuration:

```yaml
- name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: 0.15.5
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

      # Write the gcp credentials to a temp file
      - name: Setup Creds
        run: |-
            echo ${GCP_CREDS} > gcp_key.json
            cat gcp_key.json
        env: 
            GCP_CREDS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_DEFAULT }}

      # Initialize a new or existing Terraform working directory by creating initial files, loading any remote state, downloading modules, etc.
      - name: Terraform Init
        run: terraform init
```

My provider looks like this:

```yaml
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.15"
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.71.0"
    }

    google-beta = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google-beta"
      version = "3.71.0"
    }
  }
}
```

and I keep getting following issue:

[image]

Comment: Does that work locally? It looks like you have modules there with conflicting version constraints. Particularly the `3.55.0` and `3.71.0` version constraints that need to be made less constrained than that.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR BINGO!  Damn... I missed that. One of my module has provider and it seems conflict. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your modules have conflicting version constraints.

The error message shows:

```
Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/google: no available releases match the given constraints >= 2.12.0, ~> 3.45, ~> 3.53, 3.55.0, 3.71.0, <4.0.0
```

So you have modules setting each of the following [version constraints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/version-constraints.html) on the Google provider:

- >= 2.12.0
- ~> 3.45
- ~> 3.53
- 3.55.0
- 3.71.0
- <4.0.0

The conflict arises here because you have a specific version constraint on both `3.55.0` and `3.71.0` which can't then be solved.

You will need to relax the constraint on one of these to allow Terraform to be able to download the appropriate provider version.