# Configuration_aliases for multiple providers not working Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Iam having two providers for my Kubenretes which are going to be used by the modules.

Below one is the code for the version.tf file

```
 terraform {
    required_version = ">= 0.15"
    
    required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
    source = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
    version = "~> 2.11.0"
    }
    kubernetes = {
    source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
    version = "2.0.0"
    configuration_aliases = [ kubernetes.gke ]
    
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "1.7.0"
      configuration_aliases = [ kubernetes.gke_v2 ]
    }
```

So I also have a provider .tf file which having data like this

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "gke"
  host = module.gke.gke_cluster_endpoint
  token = module.gke.google_client_config_access_token
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.gke.gke_cluster_cluster_ca_certificate)
  }

  provider "kubernetes" {
  alias = "gke_v2"
  kubernetes {
  host = module.gke.gke_cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.gke.gke_cluster_cluster_ca_certificate)
  token = module.gke.google_client_config_access_token
  }
  }
```

And in my modules im adding like

```
module “istio-base” {
providers = {
kubernetes = kubernetes.gke
helm = helm.helm
}
istio_values = [file(“environment/${var.environment}/istio-values.yaml”)]
source = “”
depends_on = [module.gke, kubernetes_namespace.istio_system_namespace]
}
```

But the issue is that when im doing the terraform init command. Its only taking one version like below.

```
   *Error: Failed to query available provider packages*
    │
 Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/kubernetes: no available releases match the given constraints 1.7.0, 2.0.0
    ╵
```

MY TERRAFORM code is in 0.15.5 version.
Can anyone tell where its wrong

Comment: You can't use two versions of the same provider in the same Terraform module/run. The error message is Terraform trying to tell you that it can't download a version of the provider that meets both those requirements because you haven't specified an overlapping range.

Comment: But based on terraform docs, https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html

its possible its saying

Comment: You can have multiple provider _configurations_ (eg pointing to different AWS/Google accounts or different Kubernetes clusters) but they have to use the same version. And you can set provider version constraints so that a module might have some functionality that requires say `> v1.7.0` while another only works with `< v2.0.0` so those modules can set those constraints and Terraform will find the single latest version that satisfies those constraints.

Comment: Please have a look at [Terraform Version Constraints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/version-constraints.html) as well as this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67911483/terraform-init-reports-failed-to-query-provider-packages-via-github-actions)